# AddLive sdk ios sample app not working

Tags: ios

I just wanted to try AddLive sdk for iOS App .So downloaded sample app (AddLive_iOS_Sample-master) given at github.
It is having a textfield containing text "IOS". What we are supposed to enter there to run the app. When i try some random url's and tap on connect it shows error in LabelStatus. Any doc for that app is not available.
Can i get details for using that app or what i am doing wrong.

Following are the links i used.

Download
AddLive iOS SDK Download: http://api.addlive.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/Release/2.1.1.0/AddLive_iOS_SDK_stable.2.1.1.0.tar.gz

the sample application: https://github.com/addlive/AddLive_iOS_Sample.

cannot find out how to use sample apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (I work for AddLive) are migrating to tutorials instead of sample app: https://github.com/addlive/addlive-ios-sdk-tutorials. Please note that starting from v3 (our latest release) we have closed the downloads of SDKs. Please request SDK access here: http://www.addlive.com/request/ and let us help you with everything